# curl for R delete file on sftp

Tags: r, curl, sftp

With `library(RCurl)` I could remove files from my SFTP like so:

```r
library(RCurl)
curlPerform(
   url = sftp_url,
   quote = "rm file.txt")
)
```

How could I do the same using `library(curl)` instead of `library(RCurl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed somehow but not sure whether this is the canonical way:

```r
library(curl)
nh <- new_handle(quote = "rm test.txt")
invisible(curl_fetch_memory(sftp_url, handle = nh))
```